# How do I set precision while using type double / float in C++

Tags: c++, double, precision

In my previous question [Comparing a double and int, without casting or conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10419377/comparing-a-double-and-int-without-casting-or-conversion), I found out how the the difference between two doubles was tripping the comparison.

I came accross the method setprecision(), which will help display all the numbers after decimal.

So, the difference of 6.15 and 3.15 was found to be : 3.00000000000000044408920985006

Now, when it gets compared with 3, it returns a result saying it is greater than 3.

How do I force it to take only a limited number of digits?

When I used 6.1 and 3.1, the difference was : 2.99999999999999955591079014994

How should I make the precision so that we know that it is actually equal to 3, and not less than.

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hopefully you should be knowing that floating/double cannot be exactly represented in binary and truncation happens because of the recurring decimal. Your comparison with a float/double with an integer will always fail.

Even your using setprecision will not work because its a method of iomanip to set the precision of the display and not the value being stored.

The portable way of comparing doubles is not to use the '==' operator but to do something like

```
bool Compare(double a,double b) {
    std::fabs(a - b) < std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon();
}
```

You can use this to compare double with float and or integer. You can also write a similar compare function for float

```
bool Compare(float a,float b) {
    std::fabs(a - b) < std::numeric_limits<float>::epsilon();
}
```

Comment: The epsilon values are only appropriate if the values you're comparing are close to 1.0.

Comment: I think it should be abs(a-b) <= epsilon.  instead of <

Answer (score 3):

In a comment on your other question, you were already pointed towards [this great paper](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) on floating-point numbers. It's *well* worth a read.

With reference to your particular question, a standard way is to define a *tolerance* with which comparison between doubles is to be made. For example if you have two doubles `a` and `b`, and wish to determine whether `a` is larger than `b` within a tolerance of `eps` (another double), you might do something like:

```
if (a - b > eps) {
  // a is greater than b
} else {
  // a is not greater than b
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to know that `a` is equal to `b` within the tolerance specified by `eps`, you might do something of this sort:

```
if (std::abs(a - b) <= eps) {
  // a and b are equal within the set tolerance
} else {
  // a and b are not equal within the set tolerance
}
```

As pointed out by others, C++ comes with some helpful functions out of the box for performing these sorts of comparisons. Look at [std::abs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/abs/), [std::numeric_limits](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/limits/numeric_limits/), and [this nice post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118165/when-do-i-use-fabs-and-when-is-it-sufficient-to-use-stdabs) on SO.

Comment: You have to be careful defining the tolerance `eps` though. You might want to use [relative error](http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/comparingfloats.htm) instead.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a comparison function that determines if two numbers are within one LSB of each other.

```
bool Compare(double a, double b)
{
    return (a <= std::nextafter(b, abs(1.1*b))) && (b <= std::nextafter(a, abs(1.1*a)));
}
```

`std::nextafter` is new to C++11, but versions are available in earlier compilers. See [Generate next largest or smallest representable floating point number without bit twiddling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7408407/generate-next-largest-or-smallest-representable-floating-point-number-without-bi)

Answer (score 1):

`setprecision` lets you select how many digits you spit out to a stream. It does not decide the number of digits to be considered. For rounding purposes use one of the rounding functions from `<cmath>`.

Answer (score 0):

The no of digits of precision in float and double actually depends on the size of them respectively.That is why float generally has less precision than double.
You can use

```
    std::cout<<std::setprecision(desired no);

    float a=(desired no);
```

Now you have sucessfully set the precision of float.The same can be done to other appropriate data type including double as well.
**Warning** do not set  precision greater than what a data type has to offer.Double has 15 to 18 digits of precision while float has only 6 to 9 digits of precision.